# Access 2010 VBA referring to single field in a table

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm currently working on a project where I have to create a prototype system for a Sweet Company/wholesaler. On my form for Customer Order Details, I have a combo box to select whether the items of stock ordered are 'Assigned' or 'Shipped'. I want to have it so that once 'Shipped' is selected, it cannot be changed back. I tried coding in VBA so that once selected the combo box changes to enabled = false. However the problem is it changes for every customer order in the system.
My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub OrderStatus_Click()
    If OrderStatus = "Shipped" Then
        OrderStatus.Enabled = False
    End If

    ' etc
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to refer to a single instance of the attribute 'Order Status' (ie. Shipped or Assigned) without affecting every single customer order? Please help!

Comment: Is the form bound to a recordset, or are you executing code to update the record somewhere? If so, please include that code.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event to your form for On_Current() so that whenever you switch to a new record it will check to see if the combo box should be enabled for that record.

```
Private Sub On_Current()
    If OrderStatus = "Shipped" Then
        OrderStatus.Enabled = False
    else
        OrderStatus.Enabled = True
    End If
end Sub
```